# Does any know what type of bike this is?

Tags: identify-this-bike

Does anyone know what kind of bike this is?

[image]

Comment: It may be an illusion of the bike being upside down but it appears your crank is lower than the back wheel?

Comment: @DanK: It only looks that way because the bike is not level (because the seat is very low).

Answer (score 5):

That's not a great photo, but I see:

- 26 inch wheels
- No front derailleur mech - (its a 1x from before that was cool?)
- Old school front suspension forks with boots over the stanchions
- V Brakes
- Interesting in-line rear shock absorber - I can't see any details of how the rear suspension hinges... there's a high chance its by the Bottom Bracket or a small possibility its all in the flex of the frame which is terrifying.

**Upshot** - its some low-end BSO from the early 2000s.  Main intended use is "comfort" flat street riding, with no big jumps or drops.  The rear suspension probably doesn't move much if at all.  Earlier bikes would have had a triple chainset because when it comes to gears, more is better for sales.  The single chainring is a cost saving.

If you want a specific brand, then that rear shock is the most distinctive feature, so start googling about for "mtb frames with rear shock in seat stay" and start digging.

Also have a very close look at the head tube and sides of the downtube looking for logos and words, or traces.  You might get lucky and find a name.

In reality, brand matters not-at-all.  It will use common 26" wheels and parts, there's no need to match brands.

Comment: That type of rear suspension, which relies on chainstay flex rather than any hinge mechanism, was fairly common for a brief while before real full suspensions were good enough and light enough to be used more widely. Often called a "softail". The travel on the spring was very short and the spring tight, so the chainstays didn't flex very much. But that also meant that the feel of the bike didn't change much. All of which is to say it helps date the bike, but isn't a really strongly distinguishing feature.

Comment: Friend of mine had a bike with a rear shock like that; there was actually a pivot point for the chain stays just behind the bottom bracket.

Comment: @DavidW possibly there is a hinge there... its a good example of what not to do when photographing your bike.